# issue with unchangable input variable in python sort

Tags: python

I am writing a series of python methods with different sorts.  What I have is user inputted numbers which I turn into a list.  I then run my bubble_sort method on the input list and I then print the result.  I have my initial input list saved so that I can re-sort using selection_sort but when I print out my original list I instead am printing the bubble_sorted list.  I am new to python so I am not sure if I am missing a fundamental concept about variables in the language.  Here is my code

```
def listify(i):
    temp_list = []
    input_list_local = []
    input_list_local = list(i)
    for char in input_list_local:
        if char.isdigit():
            temp_list.append(char)
    return temp_list


def bubble_sort(input):
    for i in range(len(input)-1):
        for j in range(len(input)-1):
            if(input[j] > input[j+1]):
                tmp = input[j]
                input[j] = input[j+1]
                input[j+1] = tmp
    return input

def selection_sort(input):
    pass


input = raw_input("enter random numbers here seperated by spaces-> ")
print("you entered "+input)
input_list = listify(input)
print(input_list)
pass_list = input_list
print(bubble_sort(pass_list))
print(input_list) #should print original input list.  Instead prints sorted list
```

Answer (score 4):

You are modifying the same list: `pass_list = input_list` means that `pass_list` is just a different name for the same list object. So after calling `bubble_sort(pass_list)` you've modified `pass_list` but also `input_list` because they're the same object (in memory). Hence you're seeing the sorted list when you're printing `input_list`.

You can fix it by doing:

```
pass_list = input_list[:]
```

This makes a copy of `input_list` by using [Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1267329). You can then safely sort `pass_list` and it won't affect the original `input_list`.